# ¿Cómo evitar recortar imágenes SVG con cropperJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery

La idea es permitirle al usuario subir imágenes de varios formatos, ejemplo: JPG, PNG, SVG. El objetivo final es permitirle recortar todas las imágenes excepto, SVG. Me gustaría indicarle a cropper que no tenga en cuenta las SVG.

**Una parte del código es la siguiente:**

```
// initialize FileReader which reads uploaded file
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onloadend = function () {

  $('.preview-container').removeClass('hidden');
  $('.crop-area').removeClass('hidden');

  // add uploaded and read image to modal
  // $('.preview-container').html($img);

  $img.attr('src', reader.result);

  // initialize cropper for uploaded image
  $img.cropper({
    viewMode: 1,
    aspectRatio: width_ / height_,
    //aspectRatio: 3 / 1,
    preview: '.preview',
  });
};
```

Interpreto que en esa función debo añadir una condición o algo que le indique a cropperJS que no quiero recortar las imágenes cuyo formato sea SVG.

Comment: Pero cual es el problema?

Comment: No quiero recortar img con formato SVG, quiero que simplemente se suban al servidor

Comment: y si colocas un `else` después del `if(file.type.match(/svg/)){ ... }`, y en el `else` iría todo el código de `$img.cropper({ ... });`...

Comment: Ese if genera un bucle infinito de peticiones! La solucion no parece tan facil como esa (sorry no tengo tildes)

Comment: me queda la duda si no quieres recortar porque usas cropper ???

Comment: La idea es permitir muchos formatos de imagenes, entre ellos, SVG. La idea es darle la posibilidad al usuario de recortar las imagenes, excepto SVG.

Comment: @yussef Ya he mejorado la pregunta!

Answer (score 0):

Puedes deshabilitar el cropper con la función `disable`. Pero cuidado que al parecer tu estas usando el wrapper de jquery y me parece que no tiene esta función, debes usarlo con Javascript puro

Aquí un ejemplo:

```
function openFile(input){
    let file = input.files[0];
      
    reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = e => {
        const image = document.getElementById('imagen');
        image.src = e.target.result;

        const cropper = new Cropper(image, {
            viewMode: 1,
            aspectRatio: 3,1,
            preview: '.preview',
        });
        if (file.name.endsWith(".svg")) {
            cropper.disable(); //desabilitamos
        }
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```